# Add text from UITextField to NSMutableArray and display it in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uitextfield

I am just starting with Objective-C to write iPhone apps. I read a couple books and made some projects with the books, but I am just not an expert yet. I am trying to add some text from a UITextField to an NSMutableArray and then display it in a UITableView. I know this is really basic stuff for most of you, but I am just a beginner. So far I have two files:
TableViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class AddItemViewController;

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController {
    AddItemViewController *addItemViewController;
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray;

}
-(IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *itemsArray;
@end
```

TableViewController.m

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "AddItemViewController.h"


@implementation TableViewController
@synthesize itemsArray;

-(id)init
{
    [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self setTitle:@"Playing Around"];

UIBarButtonItem *bbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNewItem:)];
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:bbi];
[bbi release];
return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[[self tableView] reloadData];
}

#pragma mark Actions

-(IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender
{
addItemViewController  = [[AddItemViewController alloc] init];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animations" context:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:addItemViewController animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
[UIView commitAnimations];


}

#pragma mark TableView Things

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [itemsArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
return cell;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
[itemsArray release];
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

AddItemViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class TableViewController;


@interface AddItemViewController : UIViewController {
TableViewController *tableViewController;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
NSString *value;

}
-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)create:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *value;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *itemsArray;

@end
```

AddItemViewController.m

```
#import "AddItemViewController.h"
#import "TableViewController.h"


@implementation AddItemViewController
@synthesize value, itemsArray;

-(id)init
{
[self setTitle:@"Add Item"];
UIBarButtonItem *item;
item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:item];
[item release];
item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(create:)];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:item];
[item release];
return self;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void)viewDidUnload:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidUnload];
[textField release];
textField = nil;
}

#pragma mark Actions

-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animations" context:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:tableViewController animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
[UIView commitAnimations];


}

-(IBAction)create:(id)sender
{
    //This is where I get lost
NSString *string = [textField text];
NSLog(@"The string is: %@", string);
[itemsArray addObject:string];
[[tableViewController tableView] reloadData];

NSLog(@"The items are: %@", itemsArray);

tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animations" context:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:tableViewController animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)dealloc {
[textField release];
[value release];
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

(Sorry I put the whole thing here, but for all I know I could be doing something wrong in any part of this.)
So if you want to skip most of the stuff I think I did right just go to the create: method.

Now what do I do? I got this far, but the text from the UITableView will not show up when I try to add it to the itemsArray. Any tips would be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UITableView` needs a data source. Your table view controller should implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. [Here are the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Ok. I looked at the documentation, but what exactly do I need to add to my project?

Comment: You need some object, probably the one which holds the `itemsArray`, to also implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. If you aren't familiar with how Objective-C protocols work, you can read about them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html).

Comment: So I understand what a protocol does, but now how do I put it into my application? I know this probably sounds really easy to you, but I am still just beginning. What do I have to change in the project now?

Comment: You need to update the interface of the object that will implement the protocol (in this case your `TableViewController` class). It should look like this: `@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource> {`. Once you've done that, you then need to implement any methods of the protocol, such as one which returns the number of rows in the table. See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for `UITableViewDataSource` to see which methods you need to implement.

Comment: I don't get what I am supposed to add about the UITableViewDataSource

Comment: To understand it, read the document I linked to above about protocols. The section titled "Adopting a Protocol" describes what you need to do.

Comment: So change it to `@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController<UIViewControllerDataSource> {`
But then what do I do with the rest of my code?